# How to compute distance with respect to inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is the invertible matrix :

$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 0 & 1\\
   0 & 1 & -1\\
   1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

We know that the function given by $\langle u,v\rangle = (Au)\cdot (Av) $ is an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Compute the distance between $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ with respect to this inner product.

How would you go about solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An inner product $\langle\cdot\rangle$ defines a norm by $\|x\|^2= \langle x,x\rangle$, or equivalently, $\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$. A norm defines a distance by $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$.

So the distance is $$\|(1,0,0)-(0,1,0)\|= \|(1,-1,0)\|= \sqrt{\langle (1,-1,0),(1,-1,0)\rangle} = \sqrt{A(1,-1,0)\cdot A(1,-1,0)}$$

Now compute the matrix product etc.

Comment: It makes sense. I wonder why neither https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor mentions how distance is defined (only "allows defining distance"). My current guess - it is arbitrary, norm of difference is one (most common) way... However, if so, how question "compute distance" makes sense w/out explicitly stating assumption of what distance here is?

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $Ae_i$ is the $i$-th column of $A$ so

$$\|e_1-e_2\|^2 = \|A(e_1 - e_2)\|_2^2 = \|Ae_1 - Ae_2\|_2^2 = \left\|\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\right\|^2 = 2^2 + (-1)^2 + 1^2 = 6$$

and therefore $\|e_1-e_2\| = \sqrt6$.

Comment: The answer should be root 6 not root 5? Unless I am missing something your vector should be (2,-1,1) not (2,-1,0)

Comment: @Forextrader Oh my. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If $x=(1,0,0)$ and $y=(0,1,0)$, the distance between them is given by $\| x-y\|$. And recall that, the norm is defined by $\| v\|=\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}$. Thus
$$\| x-y\|=\| (1,-1,0)\|=\sqrt{\langle (1,-1,0),(1,-1,0)\rangle }=\cdots$$

Comment: Thank you, I did actually get that far (which I should have stated in the original post) but how does matrix A tie into the result?

Comment: @Forextrader You are told that $\langle u,v\rangle = (Au)\cdot (Av)$. In the final expression given here, you have two vectors in angle brackets (the two vectors happen to be equal, but that's inconsequential). How do you think the matrix $A$ ties into the result?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: How would you *usually* calculate the distance between the two points? Can you formulate that in terms of the standard inner product? Now do the calculation with this new inner product instead of the standard one.